# OpenMP invalid controlling predicate - persistent

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I keep getting this error for >6 hours now when trying to compile C-code with -fopenmp flag using gcc.

error: invalid controlling predicate
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )

I browsed stackoverflow and I stripped down my code up till the point where it is an exact copy of an example from an OpenMP handbook, but still it doesn't compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double N; sscanf (argv[1]," %lf", &N);
    double integral = 0.0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: integral)
        for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
            integral = integral + i;

    printf("%20.18lf\n", integral);
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions..?

Comment: I gave N a constant value rather than using sscanf and it worked that way. EDIT: It works with `sscanf` too.  Check here: https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler/. Gave it 11.11 as input and all went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, sorry for the clutter..

To all other C newbies like myself: The error was in the double N. OpenMP wants your loop to run op to an INTEGER N, and not a double.

Comment: I was able to run it with double. Strange. I wanted to suggest also first that try integer, but tested it myself first with double and worked with it.

Comment: Maybe depends on the OpenMP version? I am totally inexperienced in C / OpenMP. In any case, N needs to be double in my code, but I guess I can work around this by copying it into an integer variable for the loop counts.

Comment: Who knows maybe. I am not an expert on OpenMP either, just worked with it for 2 months more than 1 year ago.